# Problema ao utilizar jQuery UI no ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

Estou tentando adicionar a "ComboBox Autocomplete" do jQuery UI no meu projeto ASP.NET MVC, mas ele diz que a função widget não é uma função.

> jquery-3.1.1.min.js: 2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $.widget is not a function TypeError: $.widget is not a function

Estou seguindo os passos do exemplo do site do jQuery ([Tutorial do jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)), a diferença é que extraí o scripts para arquivo externo e o css também.

Eu já vinculei os scripts necessários para utilizar essa função, que está na seguinte ordem:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-ui.css")">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/app/cliente/meu-css.css")">

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js")"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app/cliente/meu-script.js")"></script>
```

Eu refiz esse exemplo no bloco de notas e deu certo, mas no projeto MVC não deu.

Comment: Você tem algum problema ao carregar o JS que tem a função widget, confere os JS carregados na pagina para saber qual não foi carregado

Comment: Ricardo, todos foram carregados, inclusive o jquery-ui.js que contém a função. Isso que não entendo. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui achar o problema!

Mesmo o jQuery sendo carregado primeiramente, o meu script não encontrava a função, pois eu não estava passando o '$' no parâmetro
da função do meu script:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.widget("custom.combobox", {
        ...
    });
})();
```

Ainda não entendi o porque, nesse caso, o meu script não conseguir enxergar o jQuery sem ter que passar o '$' no parâmetro , sendo que quando fiz esse mesmo exemplo no bloco de notas não precisou fazer isso.